# Unix Domain Sockets with Python server and c client not working (socket file not found)

Tags: python, c, sockets, ipc, unix-socket

I'm new to unix domain sockets (but not entirely new to the general concept of sockets) and tried to let a server written in Python communicate with a client written in C to learn more about them. I used the code examples from https://pymotw.com/2/socket/uds.html and http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/unixsock.html. To my understanding they should be compatible. The only thing I changed was the socket path so that they are the same. However when I try to connect them (although they are in the same directory and the python server creates the socket file) the client isn't able to find the path of the socket file. When I use a Python Server and Client or C Socket and Client it works absolutely fine, but I need it to work with an Python Server and C Client. I'm running OS X, used Python 2.7 for the server and compiled the Client with gcc.

---

Edit:
Here is my Server code:

```
import socket
import sys
import os

server_address = 'echo_socket'

# Make sure the socket does not already exist
try:
    os.unlink(server_address)
except OSError:
    if os.path.exists(server_address):
        raise

# Create a UDS socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Bind the socket to the port
print >>sys.stderr, 'starting up on %s' % server_address
sock.bind(server_address)

# Listen for incoming connections
sock.listen(1)

while True:
    # Wait for a connection
    print >>sys.stderr, 'waiting for a connection'
    connection, client_address = sock.accept()
    try:
        print >>sys.stderr, 'connection from', client_address

        # Receive the data in small chunks and retransmit it
        while True:
            data = connection.recv(100)
            print >>sys.stderr, 'received "%s"' % data
            if data:
                print >>sys.stderr, 'sending data back to the client'
                connection.sendall(data)
            else:
                print >>sys.stderr, 'no more data from', client_address
                break

    finally:
        # Clean up the connection
        connection.close()
```

and here is my client code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>

#define SOCK_PATH "echo_socket"

int main(void)
{
    int s, t, len;
    struct sockaddr_un remote;
    char str[100];

    if ((s = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Trying to connect...\n");

    remote.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(remote.sun_path, SOCK_PATH);
    len = strlen(remote.sun_path) + sizeof(remote.sun_family);
    if (connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&remote, len) == -1) {
        perror("connect");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Connected.\n");

    while(printf("> "), fgets(str, 100, stdin), !feof(stdin)) {
        if (send(s, str, strlen(str), 0) == -1) {
            perror("send");
            exit(1);
        }

        if ((t=recv(s, str, 100, 0)) > 0) {
            str[t] = '\0';
            printf("echo> %s", str);
        } else {
            if (t < 0) perror("recv");
            else printf("Server closed connection\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    close(s);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Since I have no experience with UDS I'm grateful for any help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show your actual code. How can we know whether you haven't mistyped something, or just changed "this little bit", or a million other reasons why the code may not work?

Comment: I really changed just one line but okay. I'll add it. Wait a sec

Comment: Don't know if this is the root cause of your problems but the client example appears to have at least one bug in it. The [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) says: "The addrlen argument that describes the enclosing sockaddr_un structure should have a value of at least: `offsetof(struct sockaddr_un, sun_path) + strlen(addr.sun_path) + 1`". The example code is missing the `+1`.

Comment: Okay I'll try it thanks! (Although it worked with a C Server)

Comment: Yes it worked! Thank you so much!